# Can't implode array from axios call

Tags: php, arrays, axios

I'm trying to implode an array coming back from an axios call and I'm hitting an array to string conversion error.

When I hit the axios call, the payload shows the array like this:

`categories: [{id: "1"},{id: "3"}]`

then it comes into my PHP file where the function tries to implode:

```
public function implodeArray(array $categories=null){
   $categoriesTest = empty($categories) ? '' : implode(','$categories);
}
```

but I'm hitting an array to string conversion error. If I dump the array right before implosion it's in this format:

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:1 [
    "id" => "1"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [
    "id" => "3"
  ]
]
```

I'm assuming it can't implode now because the indeces aren't comma separated?

Comment: It can't implode because it is __multidimensional array__.

Comment: Ah, so it needs to be a single-level array of comma separated values?

Comment: Comma-separated values can be in string. Array is a collection of values without any commas and separations.

Comment: Try to check if it isn't already an array before exploding it. Apparently, it is a multidimensional array (field set).

Comment: @u_mulder gotcha, so in order to use the implode as is would I just want to make it a single dimensional array then?

Comment: Yes, just a list of IDs would be easier for you to process. The extra structure isn't adding anything useful because each object only has one property anyway